# Fragment to context?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

```
   listClass.add(new ListClass(json.getString("ProductId"), json
                            .getString("ProductPrice")));
            }
        list.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(Fragment1.this, listClass));
```

But in Class : MyListAdapter i'm receiving an error :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(fragment).inflate(
            R.layout.pricelist, parent, false);
```

fragment1 class extends fragment.
While in rowView = layoutinflater.from(//i can only extend context here
 and not a fragment).
What can i do??

**Update mylistadapter class :**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Fragment fragment;
    private ArrayList<ListClass> listClass = new ArrayList<ListClass>();

    public MyListAdapter(Fragment1 fragment1, ArrayList<ListClass> listClass1) {
        this.fragment = fragment1;
        this.listclass = listClass1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listClass.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ListClass.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(fragment).inflate(
                R.layout.pricelist, parent, false);

        TextView text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.details);
        text1.setText(BeanClass.get(position).phoneName);
        text2.setText(BeanClass.get(position).phonePrice);
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use this `list.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), listClass))`

Comment: Sorry i typed wrong names.. fixed it(i'm still receiving an error).

Comment: Check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: where do you intialize `LayoutInflater`?. do you pass the activity context to the constructor of the MyListAdapter and use the same ?

Comment: i didn't initialize it..

Comment: then how can you use without initializing it? show us your MyListAdapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get context of a activity use `getActvitiy()`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()

```
public final Activity getActivity ()
```

Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

```
  list.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), listClass));
```

Then in your MyListAdapter constructor

```
    Context mContext; // you can remove this
    LayoutInflater mInflater; 
    private ArrayList<ListClass> listClass = new ArrayList<ListClass>(); 
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListClass> listClass1)
    {
    mContext = context; // you can remove this
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); // get rid of this statement 
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // you can directly use context
    this.listclass = listClass1;
    }
```

Then in `getView`

```
    View rowView = mInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.pricelist, parent, false);
```

Comment: @KingOmar hmm. i am glad its was wrong click coz i think the answer was right.